# Rails Admin - Can't edit or delete items in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: reviews.restaurant_id: SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."restaurant_id" = ?
Extracted source (around line #91):

```
def prepare sql
  stmt = SQLite3::Statement.new( self, sql )
  return stmt unless block_given?

  begin

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :restaurant
end

class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, through: :reviews
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :restaurants, through: :reviews
end

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170420034712) do

  create_table "restaurants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "logo"
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "address1"
    t.string   "address2"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zipcode"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.integer  "cost"
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.string   "menu"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "comment"
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.integer  "num_visits"
    t.integer  "num_searches"
    t.integer  "num_called"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

end
```

So I am using Rails Admin I can add items to the database but then I can not delete them or edit them through Rails admin.  I am wondering if I am missing something simple.  I would think I would be able to delete or edit a user or restaurant after creating them.  I don't quite understand the error and can't find any documentation on it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have `user_id` or `restaurant_id` columns in your `reviews` table to support your `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :restaurant` associations (or their corresponding `has_many`s).

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  I just couldn't find anything saying that specifically.